# Fastest way to convert multiple dictionary to a csv table

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a for loop which creates 2 kinds of dict in each iteration of loop

```
dict1= {'a':'hello', 'b':"13/12/2019", 'c':23.45}

dict2: {'tax_type':"duties taxes", 'Charges':25.00,'Total':9.23}
```

So in some iteration of the for loop I would have the first one created and in some other iteration I would have the second one created. This repeats multiple times

In the end I want a csv file which should have both these dictionaries keys as column headers and values as row for the same iteration of for loop.

so something like:

```
a     | b         | c   | tax_type  | Charges | Total
------------------------------------------------------
hello | 13/12/2019| 23.45 |duties taxes| 25.00 | 9.23
```

When the next pass of for loop happens, then another 2 new above dict will be there and I want them to be added to the above csv as new record under same column headers.

I thought if I can keep adding these 2 dict created in each pass of the for loop to a third dict and then finally convert the final dict into a csv, that is one way. But the difficulty is how to add the values of the above dicts in each pass as an element of list.

using `dict.update(dict1)` or `dict.update(dict2)` would overwrite the previous pass dict values. I want that to become a list.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

lst = []
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
# for loop
for i in range(100):
    # simulating the staggered creation of dict1 and dict2 below
    if condition1:
        dict1 = {'a':'hello', 'b':"13/12/2019", 'c':23.45}
    if condition2:
        dict2 = {'tax_type':"duties taxes", 'Charges':25.00,'Total':9.23}
    if dict1 and dict2:
        lst.append({**dict1, **dict2})
        dict1 = {}
        dict2 = {}

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
       a           b      c      tax_type  Charges  Total
0  hello  13/12/2019  23.45  duties taxes     25.0   9.23
1  hello  13/12/2019  23.45  duties taxes     25.0   9.23
...
```

Comment: how are we going to add new records for another iteration of for loop in it?

Comment: Hi this is very helpful. I updated my question. I realized my both lists are not getting created in same iteration. There wud be some iteration where I wud hv first dict created and then others where I would have second created and that process repeats.

So we wud somehow need all these dicts to be added to a third dict and if the first dict creation process repeats again, then we can append that third dict to the list and repeat the above process.